# Proof of address UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I was wondering if including a rent contract that doesn't include a official stamp is okay or not for a UK visa application.

Comment: Please could you add some more information about your situation? There are a few possible reasons why someone would talk about a rent contact in the context of a visa application but I can't guess which might apply to you.

Comment: There is a section in the UK visa supporting documents checklist to attach a proof of address : Home address
Documents showing where you live, such as:
Property deed / mortgage statements / tenancy agreements / accountant's
letters / land registration documents

Answer (score 1):

The current [UK Visas & Immigration supporting documents guide](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) asks for *Confirmation of legal residence, if you are not a national of the country in which you are applying or your right to reside there is not included in your passport*.

What you're referring to is sometime found in a visa application checklist:

Home address
Documents showing where you live, such as:
Property deed / mortgage statements / tenancy agreements / accountant's
letters / land registration documents

In that case, you can include your rental agreement, a fully-executed (signed) original not photocopy, but it should not need an official stamp. However, if it is not in English or Welsh, it would need to be accompanied by a full translation that can be independently verified by the Home Office.